# Moscow Math Olympiad 1973

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, euclidean-geometry, contest-math

> In every polyhedron there is at least one pair of faces with the same number of sides.

Solution:

> Let $N$ be the greatest number of sides in a face of a given polyhedron. Then the number of edges of each of the N adjacent faces each has the number of sides between $3$ and $N$. There bound to be $2$ with the same number of sides.

I don't understand why "the number of edges of each of the N adjacent faces each has the number of sides between $3$ and $N$"? Anyone helps?

Comment: What's the least number of sides of a polygon? The maximum is $N$ by hypothesis.

Comment: The argument seems to depend on the fact that two faces cannot have more than one edge in common, so $N$ must be less than the number of faces.

Comment: Note that the original problem statement required to prove that for convex polyhedra only.  If two concave faces may have more than one common edge (think of the Rubik's Cube with removed edge pieces), the argument no longer holds.

Answer (score 3):

At least 3 since the face with the least amount of sides is a triangle.

At most N since you are using N to name the maximum number of sides any face in the polyhedron has. Hope that helps.

Comment: Also the argument is considering any face $F$ that has the maximum of N edges, and then thinking about the N faces that touch $F$. That is what "the N adjacent faces" means.

Answer (score 3):

Let $F$ be a face with the maximum number of sides of any face let $N$ denote that number. Then there are $N$ adjacent faces to $F$. Each face has any number of sides between $3$ and $N$( because $N$ is maximal). Now count the number of faces so far. We have the $N$ faces and $N-3$ options for number of sides. Use pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 0):

Well it cannot be more than N because this is the max by definition. Obviously it cannot be 0. It also cannot be 1 because it already has 1 joining the original face with N.

So try and rule out 2. Think about the minimum number of faces a polyhedron has.